# Definição das regras de segurança firebase

Tags: firebase, segurança, realtime-database

Como posso definir uma regra de segurança que:

1. Permita acesso de leitura e gravação as receitas se o usuário logado for o usuário que a cadastrou
2. Permita acesso de leitura as receitas se o `tipo` for `true`
3. Não permita acesso de leitura e gravação as receitas se o se o usuário logado não for o usuário que a cadastrou
4. Permitir acesso de leitura e gravação aos usuarios se o nome de usuário e senha enviados forem os mesmos cadastrados (login), imagino que seja algo com `newData`
5. Como permitir a leitura do nome de usuário, para não permitir dois usuários com o mesmo nome, da forma mais segura possível

Estrutura dos dados:

```
{
  "receitas" : {
    "-L7bAaMB-vaJhri6r-lg" : {
      "imagem" : "default",
      "ingrediente" : [ "teste" ],
      "nome" : "teste",
      "preparo" : "teste",
      "tipo" : false,
      "usuario": "-L7WxcAHr8LkfJAiI8ku"
    },
    "-L7bAqvMu8uOoY6nX5Tx" : {
      "imagem" : "example.png",
      "ingrediente" : [ "teste2" ],
      "nome" : "teste2",
      "preparo" : "teste2",
      "tipo" : true,
      "usuario": "-L7WxcAHr8LkfJAiI8ku"
    }
  },
  "usuarios" : {
    "-L7WxcAHr8LkfJAiI8ku" : {
      "senha" : "123456789",
      "usuario" : "guilherme"
    },
    "-L7bAk3EcsoOQapV9zsb" : {
      "senha" : "123456789",
      "usuario" : "patricia"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mostre as regras que você tem actualmente.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes atualmente minhas regras são publicas (`read` e `write` estão `true`)

Comment: Os pontos 1 e 3 dizem a mesma coisa ..

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes sei disso, mas para deichar bem claro...

Comment: No ponto 4, você fala de leitura e gravação em que nó? Receitas ou usuarios?

Comment: do usuário, se refere ao login

Comment: O ponto 4 ainda não está claro. Vocẽ pode dar exemplos do que é permitido e o que não é?

Comment: O ponto 4 é apenas uma forma de dois usuários cadastrarem os mesmos dados e um se conectar na conta do outro, então não pode ter dois nomes de usuarios iguais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Para verificar se o usuário logado é o usuário que cadastrou a receita, utiliza-se a variável `auth.uid` e o `newData` (no caso da escrita) ou `data` (na leitura). Isso seria:

```
"receitas":{
            "$idReceita":{
                ".write":"auth.uid == newData.child('usuario').val()",
                ".read":"auth.uid == data.child('usuario').val()"
            }
        }
```

2.É só adicionar mais uma condição na leitura que verifica o tipo: `".read":"auth.uid == data.child('usuario').val() || data.child('tipo').val() == true"`

5.Com a estrutura atual, não é possível ter nomes únicos no banco de dados. Para isso, eu recomendo que você crie um novo nó (chamarei "nomes") onde vai ter todos os nomes como chaves, pois chaves são únicas e não podem repetir-se. Esse nó ficaria assim:

```
{
    "nomes":{
        "guilherme":true,
        "patricia":true
    }
}
```

Assim, a regra para não repetir nomes seria:

```
".validate":"root.child('nomes').child(newData.child('usuario').val()).val() != true"
```

E então as regras ficariam assim:

```
{
    "rules":{
        "receitas":{
            "$idReceita":{
                ".write":"auth.uid == newData.child('usuario').val()",
                ".read":"auth.uid == data.child('usuario').val() || data.child('tipo').val() == true"
            }
        },
        "usuarios":{
            "$uid":{
                ".write":"auth.uid == $uid",
                ".read":"auth!=null",
                ".validate":"root.child('nomes').child(newData.child('usuario')).val() != true"
            }
        },
        "nomes":{
            ".write":"auth!=null",
            ".read":"auth!=null"
        }
    }
}
```

Aprenda mais sobre regras de segurança da Realtime Database [neste artigo](https://medium.com/android-dev-moz/como-funcionam-as-regras-de-seguran%C3%A7a-do-firebase-na-realtime-database-45b28cda14ad).

Comment: Poderia comentar o código explicando, por exemplo, o que é `$idReceita`?

Comment: O cifrão ( $ ) indica que trata-se de uma variável. `$idReceita` representa uma das receitas dentro do nó receita. O idReceita é a chave da receita. Na prática essa variável seria substituída por  `-L7bAaMB-vaJhri6r-lg` por exemplo

Comment: Li seus artigos sobre segurança bem interessante e aprendi mais ou menos como usar, mas como eu defino as variáveis, como o firebase vai saber que `$idReceita`, `$uid` e `auth.uid` são as chaves das receitas/usuários